# pytest doesn't find new tests when run from python console within IDE

Tags: python, pytest, blender

I have a file `test_pytest.py`

```
def test_dummy():
    assert 1 + 1 == 2
```

I can run pytest from within a python console in an IDE such as Spyder (my use case is Blender but the behavior is general for an embedded python console)

```
pytest.main(['-v','test_pytest.py'])
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /home/elfnor/anaconda3/bin/python
cachedir: Documents/python/.cache
rootdir: /home/elfnor/Documents/python, inifile: 
collecting ... collected 1 items

Documents/python/test_pytest.py::test_dummy PASSED

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

I then add another test to `test_pytest.py`, and save the file.

```
def test_dummy():
    assert 1 + 1 == 2

def test_another():
    assert 2 + 2 == 4
```

And rerun `pytest.main(['-v','test_pytest.py'])` but pytest dosen't find the new test.

I've tried reloading the pytest module, but no luck. If I kill the console (in Spyder), re-import pytest and rerun, the new test is found.

I haven't found a way to kill the console in Blender (without killing Blender). Is there a different way to force pytest to find new tests when used in a console.?

Comment: try reloading the pytest module refer [reload](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reload) , but if possible try executing your tests from command line `py.test test_pytest.py` , so that any change in your testcode is easily picked up.

Comment: After `importlib.reload(pytest)` pytest  still fails to find the missing test. In Blender the modules `bmesh`, `bpy` are only available inside Blender so running from the command line is not an option.

Comment: I've just tried a similar example using `unittest` and it can find a new test.

Comment: It looks to me that the file is cached and doesn't get refreshed. If you can run the tests from the script then you can run the script inside blender's console [see this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51159/935), or you could run your tests from the cli using `blender -b --python-expr "import pytest;pytest.main(['-v','test_pytest.py'])"` - that is assuming you don't need blenders gui for the tests.

Comment: check your pytest configuration. You can create a pytest.ini in the root of your project to indicate that pytest must search test in all *.py files

Comment: Sounds stupid, but make that Python is picking up the correct version of the file on your file system.  I would check the `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable and print out `sys.path` when the program starts.  I've gotten burned by similar stuff.